# Form action post to PHP file, then re-post data to external PHP file

Tags: php, forms, post, action

Using a HTML form action for membership registration, I want to post the data to a PHP file, then have this PHP file post the identical data to an external PHP file where the information will then be processed and stored.

Basically I want the first PHP file to be a proxy for posting to the external PHP file.

I just want to hide the final destination for where the data will be posted/processed so it won't be seen in the raw HTML.

I do have good reasons for this, any help or alternative suggestions would be really appreciated!

Edit: Just want to add that I do not have full control over the final destination where the data will be processed as it is a 3rd party service. I can change the form field names that will be posted/received though.

I am still learning PHP, so details will really help :)

Comment: php curl, just catch it and send it to the place back

Answer (score 1):

You can use $_SESSION super global variable to store the $_POST data from the first php file like:
`$_SESSION['first_page']=$_POST;`
And use this data in the second page.

Answer (score 0):

two way:
   1,use web service(apache or nginx) rewrite. You can google "rewrite".
   2,use php curl in the first php.

Comment: Don't really think this constitutes as an answer

Answer (score 0):

First store post data in session like this.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['myfirst_page']= $_POST;
```

and retrieve in another page like this.

```
session_start();

$mydata = $_SESSION['myfirst_page'];
```